# Azure security center ARM template enable standard plan for all resources

Tags: azure

I can select the pricing tier in ARM template but that will just set pricing tier as standard and cover VMs. However, I would like have SQL servers and app services covered as well. What do I need to add to my my template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason I did not get Kathrines template working so I made very simple template which works.

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "pricing": {
        "type": "string",
        "allowedValues": [
            "Standard",
            "Free"
        ]
    }
},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Security/pricings",
        "apiVersion": "2017-08-01-preview",
        "name": "default",
        "properties": {
            "pricingTier": "[parameters('pricing')]"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Security/pricings",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
        "name": "SqlServers",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Security/pricings/default')]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "pricingTier": "[parameters('pricing')]"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Security/pricings",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
        "name": "AppServices",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Security/pricings/SqlServers')]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "pricingTier": "[parameters('pricing')]"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Security/pricings",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
        "name": "VirtualMachines",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Security/pricings/AppServices')]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "pricingTier": "[parameters('pricing')]"
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: You should probably accept your answer as correct then ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "pricingTierVMs": {
            "type": "string",
            "allowedValues": [
                "Standard",
                "Free"
            ],
            "defaultValue": "Standard",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Specify the Azure Security Center pricing tier for VMs"
            }
        },
        "pricingTierSqlServers": {
            "type": "string",
            "allowedValues": [
                "Standard",
                "Free"
            ],
            "defaultValue": "Standard",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Specify the Azure Security Center pricing tier for SQL Servers"
            }
        },
        "pricingTierAppServices": {
            "type": "string",
            "allowedValues": [
                "Standard",
                "Free"
            ],
            "defaultValue": "Standard",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Specify the Azure Security Center pricing tier for App Services"
            }
        },
        "autoProvisioning":{
            "type": "string",
            "allowedValues": [
                "On",
                "Off"
            ],
            "defaultValue": "On",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Turn automatic deployment by ASC of the MMA (OMS VM extension) on or off"
            }
        },
        "workspaceName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Specify the name of your custom Log Analytics workspace to collect ASC data."
            }
        },
        "workspaceSubscriptionId": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Specify the subscriptionId where the custom Log Analytics workspace is deployed."
            }
        },
        "workspaceResourceGroup": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Specify the resource group where the custom Log Analytics workspace is deployed."
            }
        },
        "emailSecurityContact":{
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "email address of the contact, in the form of john@doe.com"
            }
        },
        "phoneSecurityContact":{
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "phone number of the Security Contact"
            }
        },
        "alertNotifications":{
            "type": "string",
            "allowedValues": [
                "On",
                "Off"
            ],
            "defaultValue": "On",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Send alert notifications to Security Contact"
            }
        },
        "alertsToAdmin":{
            "type": "string",
            "allowedValues": [
                "On",
                "Off"
            ],
            "defaultValue": "On",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Send alert notifications to Admins"
            }
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Security/pricings",
            "apiVersion": "2017-08-01-preview",
            "name": "VirtualMachines",
            "properties": {
            "pricingTier": "[parameters('pricingTierVMs')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Security/pricings",
            "apiVersion": "2017-08-01-preview",
            "name": "SqlServers",
            "properties": {
            "pricingTier": "[parameters('pricingTierSqlServers')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Security/pricings",
            "apiVersion": "2017-08-01-preview",
            "name": "AppServices",
            "properties": {
            "pricingTier": "[parameters('pricingTierAppServices')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Security/autoProvisioningSettings",
            "name": "default",
            "apiVersion": "2017-08-01-preview",
            "properties":{
                "autoProvision": "[parameters('autoProvisioning')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Security/workspaceSettings",
            "apiVersion": "2017-08-01-preview",
            "name": "default",
            "properties": {
                "workspaceId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('workspaceSubscriptionId'), '/resourceGroups/', parameters('workspaceResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', parameters('workspaceName'))]",
                "scope": "[subscription().id]"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Security/",
            "apiVersion": "2017-08-01-preview",
            "name": "default",
            "properties": {

            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Security/securityContacts",
            "name": "default1",
            "apiVersion": "2017-08-01-preview",
            "properties":{
            "email": "[parameters('emailSecurityContact')]",
            "phone": "[parameters('phoneSecurityContact')]",
            "alertNotifications": "[parameters('alertNotifications')]",
            "alertsToAdmins": "[parameters('alertsToAdmin')]"
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
```

Comment: Could you paste the whole template? I cannot figure out where to add it so that it does not complain about the scope.

Comment: I get "Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'default' at line '87' and column '9' is not valid." 
when deploying that. I use "New-AzDeployment" command

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated full template for deploying Security Center on an existing log analytics workspace which will enable the new (including preview) pricings.

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "autoProvisioning": {
        "type": "string",
        "allowedValues": [
            "On",
            "Off"
        ],
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Turn automatic deployment by ASC of the MMA (OMS VM extension) on or off"
        }
    },
    "workspaceName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Specify the name of your custom Log Analytics workspace to collect ASC data."
        }
    },
    "workspaceSubscriptionId": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Specify the subscriptionId where the custom Log Analytics workspace is deployed."
        }
    },
    "workspaceResourceGroup": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Specify the resource group where the custom Log Analytics workspace is deployed."
        }
    },
    "emailSecurityContact": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "email address of the contact, in the form of john@doe.com"
        }
    },
    "phoneSecurityContact": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "phone number of the Security Contact"
        }
    },
    "alertNotifications": {
        "type": "string",
        "allowedValues": [
            "On",
            "Off"
        ],
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Send alert notifications to Security Contact"
        }
    },
    "alertsToAdmin": {
        "type": "string",
        "allowedValues": [
            "On",
            "Off"
        ],
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Send alert notifications to Admins"
        }
    },
    "securitySettings": {
        "type": "string",
        "allowedValues": [
            "On",
            "Off"
        ],
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Turn security policy settings On or Off."
        }
    },
    "pricing": {
        "type": "string",
        "allowedValues": [
            "Standard",
            "Free"
        ],
        "defaultValue" : "Standard"
    }
},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Security/autoProvisioningSettings",
        "name": "default",
        "apiVersion": "2017-08-01-preview",
        "properties": {
            "autoProvision": "[parameters('autoProvisioning')]"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Security/workspaceSettings",
        "apiVersion": "2017-08-01-preview",
        "name": "default",
        "properties": {
            "workspaceId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('workspaceSubscriptionId'), '/resourceGroups/', parameters('workspaceResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', parameters('workspaceName'))]",
            "scope": "[subscription().id]"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Security/securityContacts",
        "name": "default1",
        "apiVersion": "2017-08-01-preview",
        "properties": {
            "email": "[parameters('emailSecurityContact')]",
            "phone": "[parameters('phoneSecurityContact')]",
            "alertNotifications": "[parameters('alertNotifications')]",
            "alertsToAdmins": "[parameters('alertsToAdmin')]"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Security/policies",
        "apiVersion": "2015-06-01-preview",
        "name": "default",
        "properties": {
            "policyLevel": "Subscription",
            "name": "default",
            "unique": "Off",
            "logCollection": "Off",
            "recommendations": {
                "patch": "[parameters('securitySettings')]",
                "baseline": "[parameters('securitySettings')]",
                "antimalware": "[parameters('securitySettings')]",
                "diskEncryption": "[parameters('securitySettings')]",
                "acls": "[parameters('securitySettings')]",
                "nsgs": "[parameters('securitySettings')]",
                "waf": "[parameters('securitySettings')]",
                "sqlAuditing": "[parameters('securitySettings')]",
                "sqlTde": "[parameters('securitySettings')]",
                "ngfw": "[parameters('securitySettings')]",
                "vulnerabilityAssessment": "[parameters('securitySettings')]",
                "storageEncryption": "[parameters('securitySettings')]",
                "jitNetworkAccess": "[parameters('securitySettings')]"
            },
            "pricingConfiguration": {
                "selectedPricingTier": "[parameters('pricing')]"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Security/pricings",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
        "name": "SqlServers",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Security/policies/default')]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "pricingTier": "[parameters('pricing')]"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Security/pricings",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
        "name": "AppServices",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Security/pricings/SqlServers')]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "pricingTier": "[parameters('pricing')]"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Security/pricings",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
        "name": "VirtualMachines",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Security/pricings/AppServices')]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "pricingTier": "[parameters('pricing')]"
        }
    }
    ,
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Security/pricings",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
        "name": "SqlServerVirtualMachines",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Security/pricings/VirtualMachines')]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "pricingTier": "[parameters('pricing')]"
        }
    }
    ,
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Security/pricings",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
        "name": "StorageAccounts",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Security/pricings/SqlServerVirtualMachines')]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "pricingTier": "[parameters('pricing')]"
        }
    }
    ,
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Security/pricings",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
        "name": "KubernetesService",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Security/pricings/StorageAccounts')]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "pricingTier": "[parameters('pricing')]"
        }
    }
    ,
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Security/pricings",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
        "name": "ContainerRegistry",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Security/pricings/KubernetesService')]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "pricingTier": "[parameters('pricing')]"
        }
    }
    ,
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Security/pricings",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
        "name": "KeyVaults",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Security/pricings/ContainerRegistry')]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "pricingTier": "[parameters('pricing')]"
        }
    }
],
"outputs": {}
```

}